# Python "if" statement ignored

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop, logical-operators

I'm triggering loop within loop in Python, if one of the multiple conditions ("or") is met.
The script seems to skip the "if" statement and enters inner loop without meeting required conditions.

**Code**

```
# Begin TestCase
# Main logic: execute RemoteController macro, if expected state == true, set 'Success', else: Fail
for macroname_n in range (32):
    handler("RemoteController", "SET", "[{0}_{1}_{2}]".format(testcase, macroname_n, platform), "")
    result = pbc_json(disk, testcase_area, testcase, platform, filename_n, coord_n)
    filename_n += 1
    coord_n += 1
    if macroname_n == 15 or 20:
        success_counter = 0
        for extra_loop in range(15):
            handler("RemoteController", "SET", "\"down 4\"", "")
            result = pbc_json(disk, testcase_area, testcase, platform, filename_n, coord_n)
            filename_n += 1
            if result >= 50:
                success_counter += 1
        if success_counter <> 15:
            result = 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to say `if macroname_n in (15, 20):` or `if macroname_n == 15 or macroname_n == 20:`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line does not do what you want:

```
if macroname_n == 15 or 20:
```

This is parsed as follows:

```
if (macroname_n == 15) or (20):
```

Since `20` is always true in a boolean context, the statement is always true. What you actually want is this:

```
if macroname_n in (15, 20):
```

Answer (score 3):

`20` always evaluates to `true` in a boolean context. Therefore, `macroname_n == 15 or 20` is always `true`.

You probably want to write:

```
if macroname_n == 15 or macroname_n == 20:
    success_counter = 0
    # ...
```

Comment: Or `macroname in (15, 20)`

Comment: @Paolo, sure, but would a tuple actually be worth it when comparing against only two values?

Answer (score 1):

```
if macroname_n == 15 or 20:
```

should be:

```
 if macroname_n == 15 or macroname_n == 20:
```

otherwise will it always read 20 as true.